# Индивидуальное количество товара в корзине

Tags: php, cart

Храню данные корзины в сессии. При добавлении в корзину из карточки первого товара, товар и количество добавляется корректно. При добавлении следующего товара, количество товара в корзине меняется у всех товаров, включая первый. Как сделать так, чтобы количество менялось индивидуально.

Обработчик:

```
// получаем переменные из карточки товара (id и количество)
$item_id = $_POST['id'];
$qty = $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty'] + $_POST['qty'];

//данные для отображения в корзине
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ 
    $product_name = $row["name"]; 
    $product_price = $row["price"]; 
    $product_price_sale = $row["saleprice"]; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id='$item_id'";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ $image = $row["image"]; } } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

} } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

if ($product_price_sale == ""){
    $finalprice = $product_price . ' р';
} else $finalprice = $product_price_sale . ' р';

//изменение данных сессии
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = ['id' => $item_id, 'image' => $image, 'name' => $product_name, 'qty' => $qty , 'price' => $finalprice];

include "../blocks/cart.php";

?>
```

Comment: Приведенный код не меняет ничего кроме указанного товара :) (```$_POST['id']```)

Comment: затык именно в этой части: `$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = ...` новые товары добавляются в корзину, но у всех у них меняется количество на то, которое выбрано в последнем добавленном товаре. Может быть как-то это строку в foreach обернуть?

Comment: правки:
$item_id = (int) $_POST['id'];
и кавычки в запросе не нужны WHERE id=$item_id";
а еще правильнее bind параметров делать

Comment: @MichaelChechin а если id - не число? а строка? откуда инсайд что там именно число? =)

Comment: @МихаилГорячев тот код который приведен в примере - не вызывает описанной вами ошибки, возможно что то еще за границами указанного кода происходит, попробуйте код из ответа - если он работает верно - у вас проблема со стабильностью переменной ```$item_id```.

Comment: @Владимир _Клыков
   потому что id это общепринято число, и скорее автоинкриментное. Если хочется какуюто строку то это артикул, SKU, серийный номер и тд

Comment: Простите кем это "общепринято" что id это всегда число? я часто сталкиваюсь с обратным на практике :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
// получаем переменные из карточки товара (id и количество)
$item_id = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty'] = (int)($_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty']??0) + (int)$_POST['qty'];

//данные для отображения в корзине
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ 
    $product_name = $row["name"]; 
    $product_price = $row["price"]; 
    $product_price_sale = $row["saleprice"]; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id='$item_id'";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ $image = $row["image"]; } } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

} } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

if ($product_price_sale == ""){
    $finalprice = $product_price . ' р';
} else $finalprice = $product_price_sale . ' р';

//изменение данных сессии
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = ['id' => $item_id, 'image' => $image, 'name' => $product_name, 'qty' => $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty'] , 'price' => $finalprice];

include "../blocks/cart.php";

?>
```